# Add Javascript in AMP Pages

Tags: javascript, amp-html

Please help me understand how to add javascript in the AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages). My requirement is I get an ID in URL. For example localhost:8080/home?id=1.I would like to access that id in my html file.

or else please let me know how to add any javascript file.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running JavaScript in AMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40237295/running-javascript-in-amp)

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, you cannot add arbitrary scripts in AMP.  From [the specification](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec), under "HTML Tags," for the tag `script`:

> Prohibited unless the type is `application/ld+json`.  (Other non-executable values may be added as needed.)  Exception is the mandatory script tag to load the AMP runtime and the script tags to load extended components.

So, if you want to use JavaScript from AMP, you have to use AMP's predefined [components](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components).  I don't see a component that does what you want.

Comment: we can add javascript by using <iframe> but not sure how to

Comment: I realize this has got to be simple ignorance on my part, but coming at this as an AMP newbie, this design sounds insane. "We've create this thing called jQuery to make web development much easier. Now, if you don't want to kill your Google rankings by not catering primarily to mobile users, you can't use it."

Answer (score 7):

As of 11th of April 2019 [Official Announcement](https://twitter.com/AMPhtml/status/1116378847937613824),

it is now possible using your JS inside an AMP project with `amp-script` component.

First you need to import it to your project:

1. At the top of your `.html` file import:

```
<script async custom-element="amp-script" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-script-0.1.js"></script>
```

2. Wrap the `html` element/s with the `amp-script` component:

```
<!-- hello-world.html -->
<amp-script layout="container" src="https://yourdomain.com/hello-world.js">
  <button id="hello">Insert Hello World!</button>
</amp-script>
```

3. Now you can create the JS file

```
// hello-world.js
const button = document.getElementById('hello');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const el = document.createElement('h1');
  el.textContent = 'Hello World!';
  // `document.body` is effectively the <amp-script> element.
  document.body.appendChild(el);
});
```

You can find more details and how it works in the 
AMP git repo [amp-script.md](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-script/amp-script.md)

Comment: this is experimental and cannot be used in production yet!

Comment: @Exlord Im pretty sure im using it.. can you back this up? Maybe I missed something

Comment: could u share a simple usable html ? for me its says in the console that I don't have the experimental token or something !! the tokens are bind to domain as far as I know and my widget is gana be used in clients sites and they need to get the token themselves, and Its unacceptable for my employer

Comment: somehow cookies thing not working in amp-script as well

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, you can add Javascript to AMP by hosting the AMP script on your origin and intercept the request to get the script using a Service Worker. This technique is called "AMP as PWA". Here is the code

```
function createCompleteResponse (header, body) {
  return Promise.all([
    header.text(),
    getTemplate(RANDOM STUFF AMP DOESN’T LIKE),
    body.text()
  ]).then(html => {
    return new Response(html[0] + html[1] + html[2], {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
      }
    });
  });
}
```

More explanation here: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/12/progressive-web-amps/#amp-as-pwa

Comment: It's a nice solution, but unfortunately, Service Workers are not yet supported on iOS safari: https://caniuse.com/#feat=serviceworkers (normally if you create an AMP page, is to target mobile platforms, right?)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript blocks DOM construction and delays page rendering, so AMP allows only asynchronous Javascript - AMP pages can't include any custom Javascript. Interactive page features can be handled in custom AMP elements instead of using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Custom javascript is disallowed on AMP pages, and is one of the founding principles of AMP. You can put custom js within an amp-iframe, as long as the amp-iframe is xdomain'd from the main page.

Comment: FYI, you could make this answer even better by providing a source that supports your claim.