# AMP How to dynamically get href from link with ref

Tags: javascript, html, amp-html

I am in a situation where I want to get the **href** from the **canonical** url of my **AMP web page** and add it to a an **AMP button** where upon the button **tap** the event opens a new page with the canonical URL instead.

I want to do this dynamically via code.

I could use amp-binding but I do not want to add any amp-binding to the canonical URL.

This is my AMP code with the **canonical URL** that I want to navigate to after sales button is **tapped**.

**Note**: In AMP you **tap** a button and then an action is triggered unlike in **HTML** where you would say **click**.

Would anyone know how to do this and show me how to do it please?

```html
<link rel="canonical" href="https://mysaleswebsite.com/salepage.php"/>

<div align="center" class="img-wrapper">
 <amp-img on="tap:AMP.navigateTo(url='GET_URL_FROM_CANONICAL_LINK#productX', target='_blank', opener=true)" src="img/salesbuttonpicture.jpg" height="50" width="100" alt="Sales Page">
 </amp-img>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The first thing I would do is give the corresponding tags IDs.

```
<link id="canonicalUrl" rel="canonical" href="https://mysaleswebsite.com/salepage.php"/>
<amp-img id="ampButton" src="img/salesbuttonpicture.jpg" height="50" width="100" alt="Sales Page"></amp-img>
```

Then you can reference the attributes of those element IDs to get and assign the URL accordingly.

```
<script>
    const canonicalUrl = document.getElementById('canonicalUrl').href;
    document.getElementById('ampButton').setAttribute("on", "tap:AMP.navigateTo(url='" + canonicalUrl + "#productX', target='_blank', opener=true)'")
</script>
```

I don't know anything about AMP or if this will do anything unforeseen.

Comment: Thank you Nick for your attempt to answer this Question but AMP does not even accept the <script> tag nor does it allow for accessing the DOM directly. It is a really scaled down version of HTML lacking many features of HTML.

Comment: My apologies, I was unaware of how restricted AMP is.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43748634/add-javascript-in-amp-pages