# Add current page URL in input in AMP page

Tags: javascript, html, amp-html

I just want to ask that how do I add current URL in an input of form, so I can save it where I want to save.
I have tried simple Javascript, succeed but amp page become invalid.

My code is as follows

```
<form method="GET" class="p2" action="SUBMIT URL" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="redirect" />
    <div class="block-width2">
        <div class="col-md-6"><p><input name="name" placeholder="Full Name *" type="text" required /></p></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p data-aos="fade-left" class="aos-init aos-animate"><input name="Email" placeholder="E-mail ID *" type="email" required /></p>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="block-width2">
            <div class="col-md-5"><p><input name="Mobile" placeholder="Contact No.*" type="text" required /></p></div>
            <div class="col-md-7"><p><input name="city" placeholder="City*" required type="text"></p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="block-width2">
            <div class="col-md-12"><p><input name="comments" placeholder="Comments*" required  type="text" /></p></div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="vendor" value="VMware" />
        <input type="hidden" name="course" value="VMware Training" />
        <input type="hidden" name="url" id="url" value="" /> //Here I want page URL.
        <div class="block-width2">
            <div class="col-md-12"><p><button class="button-set" type="submit">Submit Now </button></p></div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>document.getElementById("url").value  = location.href;</script> // working with invalid AMP
```

Comment: show us the javascript that you have tried.

Comment: Edited... Please check

Comment: make sure your amp page get's loaded with `<link rel="canonical" href="$SOME_URL">` to your non-amp page, this might need to be done with the use of url rewrite, i'm not sure about how amp decides on which page to load.

Comment: You cannot use custom JavaScript on an AMP page, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035733/google-amp-best-way-to-write-js-script-tag

Comment: okay.... Understood.. Thanks

Comment: @GyandeepSharma which language are you using?

Comment: @BachchaSingh Please Google AMP. My page is in simple HTML

Comment: @GyandeepSharma if it static simple html  than use url like https://example.com/ as a value in input box

Comment: Yah I know this now.... Thanks....