# The attribute 'onclick' may not appear in tag 'button'

Tags: html, amp-html

I'm facing this issue in my code while validating AMP code

> The attribute 'onclick' may not appear in tag 'button'

my code looks like

```
<button class="btn btn-primary float-right" role="button" onclick="calc();">
```

i couldn't find and answer for any related question.

Comment: i've edited the question but the issue is the title of the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If AMP whines about your use of inline `JavaScript`, simply remove it and add it in a script or an external `JavaScript` file, if you happen to have one. Just be sure to give the button an id, so that you can uniquely identify it.

**Code:**

```
<script type = "application/javascript">
   document.getElementById("button-id").onclick = calc;
</script>
```

---

**Notes:**

1. Remember that the main reason behind using AMP is to ensure that *certain technologies* don't slow down your website. Scripts, are considered one such technology and therefore, they are generally not allowed. Be sure to check out the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36035733/6313073) for more on this.
2. As a general piece of advice, I'd recommend you separate the design from the implementation part of your web applications and avoid using inline `JavaScript` altogether.

Comment: thanks you saved me and of course i'll take your advice in my consideration

Comment: @AngelPolitis Can you please explain how to add external JavaScript in AMP. How can we implement an existing amp project.

Comment: Check out my first note as well as the answers in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36035733/6313073) @BachchaSingh. JavaScript is the main reason behind slow websites and let's say AMP isn't really fond of that.