# How can I include third-party javascript

Tags: javascript, html, amp-html

When I add third-party JavaScript to my AMP website, I get the error below in the console of my browser;

> validator.js:526 AMP validation had errors:
>   validator.js:526 `http://127.0.0.1:8887/amp.html:30:4` Custom JavaScript is not allowed. (see https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/spec/amphtml#html-tags)
>   validator.js:526 `http://127.0.0.1:8887/amp.html:31:4` Custom JavaScript is not allowed. (see https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/spec/amphtml#html-tags)
>   `<script src="https://a.breaktime.com.tw/js/au.js?spj=zi"></script>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google AMP best way to write JS script tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035733/google-amp-best-way-to-write-js-script-tag)

Comment: If you tell us what exactly you need jQuery for, we can suggest a suitable alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The [`<amp-script>`](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script) component is the only way to have custom JavaScript in AMP pages while keeping them valid AMP.

The component is currently [experimental](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/experimental) and relies on the [WorkerDOM](https://github.com/ampproject/worker-dom) library to execute JavaScript inside a WebWorker.

Answer (score -1):

Custom javascript or  external JS scripts are not allowed in AMP versions its will occurs validations errors

Options :
We can able to do what ever with AMP scripts given by (https://amp.dev/documentation/components/)