# How to show element after 3 seconds in AMP page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, amp-html

I try to show the `WhatsApp` Baloon Button after 3 seconds in **AMP Page**, but it's still failed. I try to debug within `inspect` element in `Chrome` but nothing errors found.

Here're the code:

**CSS:**

```
<style amp-custom>
 .hide {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
...

<script id="script1" type="text/plain" target="amp-script">
  setTimeout(function(){
      document.getElementById('wabox').classList.remove('hide');
  }, 3000);
</script>


<a id="wabox" rel="nofollow" 
href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=XXXXXX&text=Hi%2C%20I%20am%20Interested..." 
class="wafloat hide" target="_blank">
  <i class="fa fa-whatsapp my-float gacontact wafloatx">      
      <amp-img alt="Contact us" 
                    width="64"
                    height="64"                    
                    src="img/wa-min.webp">
      </amp-img>  
  </i>
</a>

...
```

any idea?

Thank You in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `type="text/plain"` from your script declaration as it just says to the brother that it is made of text and not executed !

This is woking :

```
<script id="script1" type="text/javascript" target="amp-script">
   setTimeout(function(){
      document.getElementById('wabox').classList.remove('hide');
  }, 3000);
</script>
```

However, Javascript is often the cause of slow websites and so AMP pages do not allow them. You have a pretty good answers here about this issue:

[Best way to include custom JavaScript in AMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035733/best-way-to-include-custom-javascript-in-amp)

As seen [here](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/custom-javascript/), you could use `<amp-script>` tag in order to have your custom script working !

Comment: Hi, thank you. at first, I doubt asking this question because i think AMP has a different javascript/coding style but i can't found it on Google....

Comment: However , now i see `The attribute 'type' in tag 'script' is set to the invalid value 'text/javascript'.` after validating AMP

Comment: what happens if you delete the whole attribute?

Comment: Looks like your problem is deeper than just the attribute that was preventing the js from executing, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035733/best-way-to-include-custom-javascript-in-amp

Comment: it's executed but error just only in AMP validator, just to comply to Google AMP...